# Loading XSLT from Nextcloud

Tags: xml, xslt, cloud, drive, nextcloud

I am working with poetry creating several XML-TEI files that I export using a XSL Transformation file, located in one of my computers. Every time I need to work on XSLT I change the location of the XSL, because directories are not the same in my computers. Hence, I decided to upload my XSL to a cloud service, but I'm still struggling with it.

I've uploaded the XSL file to my own Nextcloud and I've installed [nextcloud-sharing-path](https://github.com/rookie0/nextcloud-sharing-path), forcing the sharing URL to show the file type. However, that didn't work out. Despite I use Nextcloud, I wouldn't mind trying other services.

This is the current header of my XML, pointing to the XSL through the nextcloud generated URL (which I cannot publish because of company copyright issues):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8" standalone ="no" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://.........estilos.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE TEI SYSTEM "C:/Users/mgabo/Dropbox/XML/Doc/tei.dtd">
```

XSL header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

When using the Nextcloud public XSL, Firefox shows an "unknown error" (805303f4), Internet Explorer shows the XML without styles and Chrome just a blank window.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I didn't solve the problem yet, but at least I found a workaround. Atom Browser, an extension for Atom editor, does open the URL in my nextcloud server and makes possible to preview the file with styles.

Comment: Is your question related to XML or only to Nextcloud sharing ?
Do you have successfully shared this file over Nextcloud ?
Or you have any problem with using this file in yours DevEnv ?

Comment: Both, but mainly XML, as I wouldn't mind to try other cloud services (I'm editing the question to clarify that). Yes, I've already shared other files over Nextcloud and the XSL file works correctly in my computer.

Comment: So you have problem accesing desired XML (located on Shared Nextcloud resource) , but it happens only in your Development Environment ? So as so far you not say anything about your code and DevEnv / Language.

Comment: So how do you run the XSLT? Browser based XSLT 1.0 trying to reference an XSLT stylesheet using an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction is usually restricted by the same origin policy so check the browser's error console whether it has simply refused to load or apply the XSLT due to that policy.

Comment: I've edited the question to add more information. I have problems accesing the XSL on the cloud, but it works locally.

Comment: In my understanding browsers don't allow loading an XSLT over HTTP(S) in a file loaded from the local file system so if you have that `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://.........estilos.xsl"?>` in a file on a local file system the same origin policy prevents the browser from applying the stylesheet on the HTTP server. But there is usually an error or warning in the browser console (F12) saying that.

Comment: Thanks! After reading your comment I thought that maybe editors built-in browsers may solve the issue, and I found that Atom Browser does.